# call a method as argument in other method - python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python PL. i have a doubt like this:

my method:

```
def preprocess(json_data):
    for rates in json_data['query']['results']['rate']:
        map_dict
        map_dict['rate'] = rates['Rate']
```

and i wanted to pass this method as argument in other method who has **json_data** variable.

```
def read_currency_data(self, request_url, response_type, preprocess=None):
    parse_url = urllib.urlopen(request_url).read()
        json_data = json.loads(parse_url)
        json_data.preprocess(json_data)
```

So, as i call **preprocess(json_data)** it should evaluate my json_data variable. my existing code gives traceback:

```
ValueError: "'dict' object has no attribute 'preprocess'"
```

Please guide me to achieve my goal. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
    json_data.preprocess(json_data)
```

into just

```
    preprocess(json_data)
```

because, as the error message says, `json_data` is a `dict` object, and when you do `json_data.preprocess` you're trying to find a method called `preprocess` on the `dict` class, which is not defined. Instead, you need a *function* (not a method).

Comment: @Amandan i tried it, and when i tried to print preprocess(json_data), it gives None. so i guess it is not evaluating json_data, so how could i get evaluated json_data with preprocess method?? thanks for response

Comment: You are not `return`-ing anything from `preprocess`, so returns `None`.